# Java hashmap key value iterator

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap when i am printing this hashmap the output is like this

```
{KEY_CH_UP=KEY_CH_UP, KEY_PANEL_CH_UP=KEY_PANEL_CH_UP, KEY_7=KEY_7, KEY_6=KEY_6, KEY_5=null}
```

Now i want to get all the keys which is having

```
values == null ;
```

Comment: and what have you tried to get what you want? Read [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @GauravSakhardande: I agree, great blog. But I'm **not** the author ;)

Comment: I do not see how Java EE is relevant here. HashMap is a part of standard Java SE. Retaging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the like below and check if the value is null :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> en: map.entrySet()){
            if(en.getValue()==null){
                System.out.println(en.getKey());
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 Basically the OP is searching a Map by value.  It doesn't have a more efficient way of doing this than iterating over every value which is why searching by value could indicate a poor design choice.